# How to change offsets of matplotlib LineCollection after creation

Tags: python, matplotlib

I would like to create a stack of line plots using a LineCollection. The following code draws two identical sine curves offset from one another by (0, 0.2):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.collections
import numpy as np

x=np.arange(1000)
y=np.sin(x/50.)
l=zip(x,y)

f=plt.figure()
a=f.add_subplot(111)
lines=matplotlib.collections.LineCollection((l,l), offsets=(0,0.2))
a.add_collection(lines)
a.autoscale_view(True, True, True)
plt.show()
```

So far so good. The problem is that I'd like to be able to adjust that offset after creation. Using `set_offsets` doesn't seem to behave as I expect it to. The following, for instance, has no effect on the graph

```
a.collections[0].set_offsets((0, 0.5))
```

BTW, the other set commands (e.g. `set_color`) work as I expect. How do I change the spacing between curves after they have been created?

Comment: Hmm, not sure. I observe the same problem. You could just create a new axis, right?

Answer (score 1):

I think you found a bug in matplotlib, but I have a couple work arounds.  It looks like `lines._paths` gets generated in `LineCollection().__init__` using the offsets you provide.  `lines._paths` is not property updated when you call `lines.set_offsets()`.  In your simple example, you can re-generate the paths since you still have the originals laying around.

```
lines.set_offsets( (0., 0.2))
lines.set_segments( (l,l) )
```

You can also manually apply your offsets.  Remember that you're modifying the offset points.  So to get an offset of 0.2, you add 0.1 to your pre-existing offset of 0.1.

```
lines._paths[1].vertices[:,1] += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @matt for your suggestion. Based on that I've hacked together the following which shifts the curves according to new offset values, but takes into account the old offset values. This means I don't have to retain the original curve data. Something similar might be done to correct the set_offsets method of LineCollection but I don't understand the details of the class well enough to risk it.

```
def set_offsets(newoffsets, ax=None, c_num=0):
    '''
        Modifies the offsets between curves of a LineCollection

    '''

    if ax is None:
        ax=plt.gca()

    lcoll=ax.collections[c_num]
    oldoffsets=lcoll.get_offsets()

    if len(newoffsets)==1:
        newoffsets=[i*np.array(newoffsets[0]) for\
         (i,j) in enumerate(lcoll.get_paths())]
    if len(oldoffsets)==1:
        oldoffsets=[i*oldoffsets[0] for (i,j) in enumerate(newoffsets)]

    verts=[path.vertices for path in lcoll.get_paths()]

    for (oset, nset, vert) in zip(oldoffsets, newoffsets, verts):
        vert[:,0]+=(-oset[0]+nset[0])
        vert[:,1]+=(-oset[1]+nset[1])

    lcoll.set_offsets(newoffsets)
    lcoll.set_paths(verts)
```